# Python replace timestamp values in column with correct date value of same column until next date value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I am relatively new to python and pandas. I have a dataset with a date column that starts with a date and then is followed by many rows of timestamps until the next date value appears. Here is some sample data:

```
7/12/2022
3:47:57AM
3:47:58AM
3:51:27AM
3:52:06AM
7/13/2022
4:18:20AM
4:19:05AM
4:25:51AM
4:27:50AM
```

I want to use the date value to replace the following timestamps until the next date appears and then use that date to replace the following rows of timestamp values. I want the output to look like the below:

```
7/12/2022
7/12/2022
7/12/2022
7/12/2022
7/12/2022
7/13/2022
7/13/2022
7/13/2022
7/13/2022
7/13/2022
```

I am trying to do this in python pandas. Below is the code for dataframe.

```
 df = pd.DataFrame(["7/12/2022","3:47:57AM"," 3:47:58AM","3:51:27AM","3:52:06AM","7/13/2022","4:18:20AM","4:19:05AM","4:25:51AM","4:27:50AM"], columns=['Date'])
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Naveed thank you! This does work. However, I didnt mention that my data has additional columns. It seems that when I run this code it is applied to all of the columns. Is there a way to only apply this to the date column?

Comment: Add the column name to the DF before the .mask. solution updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using [mask](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html?highlight=mask#pandas.DataFrame.mask), make the values ending with "M" (so it covers AM and PM), to null ([np.nan](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/constants.html?highlight=nan#numpy.nan)) and then do a [ffill](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html?highlight=ffill#pandas.DataFrame.ffill)

```
#makes the value as np.nan (its a default value anyways), where condition is met 
#and then forward fill to update the null values with the previous row value

df['Date']=df['Date'].mask(df['Date'].str.endswith('M')==True, np.nan).ffill()
df
```

OR

```
df['Date']=df['Date'].mask(df['Date'].str.endswith('M') ).ffill()
df
```

```
Date
0   7/12/2022
1   7/12/2022
2   7/12/2022
3   7/12/2022
4   7/12/2022
5   7/13/2022
6   7/13/2022
7   7/13/2022
8   7/13/2022
9   7/13/2022
```

Comment: would you mind if you have time explaining the function of np.nan and ffill in this scenario?

Comment: @CatDad, updated explanation and added links. hope it helps

Comment: @Naveed, This is incredible! Thank you so much for your help!